# por que o pré-decremento gera problema como argumento de uma função? por que o ex1 não funciona corretamente?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fatorial(int num);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

cout<< factorial(5);

return 0;
}

int factorial(int num)`{`

if(num > 1)

{
```

**Ex1:**

***//saida:*** Faz o fatorial de 4, não sei o porque da errado, e sempre um a menos, por exemplo, se na chamada da função fosse fatorial(6), o resultado seria o fatorial de 5, se fosse fatorial(10) a saída seria o resultado do fatorial de 9

```
ex1: return num* factorial(--num);
```

**Ex2:**

***output:*** 120, isso funciona perfeitamente.

```
ex2: return num* factorial(num - 1);

}
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Tente responder: qual é o valor de `num` depois de fazer `--num`? E depois de fazer `num-1`?

Comment: O mesmo valor. Coloquei um cout<<num<<endl antes da condicional if, e testei as duas maneiras. A saida foi a mesma, com excecao do resultado do fatorial.  O fatorial com   
*num-1* da o resultado correto e o fatorial com ***--num*** gera um resultado quase certo, ja que ele me da o fatorial do numero antecessor, se eu colocar num = 5, me da o fatorial de 4 ou seja 24, sendo que deveria ter saido 120... nao sei se estou explicando direito

Comment: Não foi isso que o colega quis dizer, é que `--num` altera o valor de `num` – e isso ocorre antes da sua multiplicação pelo resultado da função.

Comment: Eu acho q eu entendi

Comment: Entao nao tem jeito, tem que colocar ***num -1*** mesmo, pq se colocar *-num* ele vai trocar o valor da variavel e se colocar *num--* da loop infinito, muito obrigado aos dois.

Comment: Isto está bem explicado aqui https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou tentar explicar da forma que eu entendi o que está acontecendo, se por acaso eu em errar em algo me corrijam.

No **Ex1** para ser feita a multiplicação de **num * fatorial(--num)** é preciso avaliar primeiro os valores dos dois operandos, por mais que a precedência da multiplicação(*) e pré-decremento(--) seja a mesma, quando for feita a avaliação do segundo operando **num** será decrementado afetando o **num** do outro operando, fazendo com que a multiplicação seja feita com o valor de **num** já decrementado.

Para instruções que usam mais de uma expressão e a mesma variável mais de uma vez e o valor dela é alterado em uma das expressões isso pode causar comportamentos indefinidos e travar a aplicação, e isso deve ser evitado, nesse casos altere o valor da variável antes ou depois de usar ela nessas instruções.

No **Ex2** a expressão **num - 1** é avaliado formando um novo valor que será copiado para a função **fatorial**, **num** não é alterado nesse processo, fazendo com que a multiplicação seja efetuada com os valores corretos.

**OBS**: Para você ter executado este código de Ex1 você deveria estar com as flags de erro do seu compilador desativada, porque quando fui testar no g++ ele nem compilou o código e emitiu o seguinte erro:

error: operation on ‘num’ may be undefined [-Werror=sequence-point]

Verifique e ative as flags de erro do seu compilador, se você utilizar o g++ pode usar as seguintes flags:

-pedantic-errors -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -Wsign-conversion -Werror

Comment: pow é verdade, eu não tinha percebido que o ***--num*** é  na verdade ***num = num-1*** e nao ***num - 1***, realmente ele muda o valor da variável. Eu uso vs code pra fazer os codigos entao eu posso ter desativado sem querer, quando tentava configurar para o c++ no vs code.